# matlab crash dump log file

Tags: matlab

I installed matlab 2016 and it crashed when I started it. The problem is reproducible. Why does it happen?

```
MATLAB crash file:/home/dac/matlab_crash_dump.3815-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Tue Apr 19 02:44:12 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Visual      : 0x20 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.21 stable
  Host Name           : dac-Latitude-E7450
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
  Operating System    : Linux 4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 22:15:45 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11702000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f60ea915160
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000003
  RSP = 00007f617fff7550  RBP = 00007f617fff7670
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f60ea914350

   R8 = 0000000000000018   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 00007f60ea914000  R11 = 00007f60ea915478
  R12 = 00007f60eab80fa0  R13 = 0000000000000006
  R14 = 00007f60ea914758  R15 = 00007f610061f8e0

  RIP = 00007f619fdb490a  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f619fdb490a                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00051466
[  1] 0x00007f619fdbd501                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087297
[  2] 0x00007f619fdb84b4                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066740
[  3] 0x00007f619fdbc9f3                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084467
[  4] 0x00007f619d4fdfc9                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004041
[  5] 0x00007f619fdb84b4                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066740
[  6] 0x00007f619d4fe62d                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005677
[  7] 0x00007f619d4fe061                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004193 dlopen+00000049
[  8] 0x00007f6199d490b6      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00315574
[  9] 0x00007f6199d49c76      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318582 _Z11utGetModuleRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPi+00000022
[ 10] 0x00007f6199d49d6b      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318827 utGetModule+00000171
[ 11] 0x00007f618e7a1d45 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00482629
[ 12] 0x00007f618e794eaf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00429743 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000031
[ 13] 0x00007f618e78be95 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00392853 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 14] 0x00007f618e7895e9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00382441 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000057
[ 15] 0x00007f618b93b42e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10728494
[ 16] 0x00007f618b93b4c9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10728649
[ 17] 0x00007f618b6a3e1c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08011292
[ 18] 0x00007f618b71e45a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08512602
[ 19] 0x00007f618b71f83c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08517692
[ 20] 0x00007f618e1a0c86 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03157126 inCallFcnWithTrap+00000086
[ 21] 0x00007f618e22d25c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03732060 inMexCallMATLAB+00000348
[ 22] 0x00007f618da2f2af     /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00098991 mexCallMATLAB+00000063
[ 23] 0x00007f618cdab108  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_ir.so+00246024 mps_call_constant_mxarray_function_constant+00000184
[ 24] 0x00007f618d1f369c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_parser.so+02111132
[ 25] 0x00007f6189a26999 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00055705
[ 26] 0x00007f6189a2983e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00067646
[ 27] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 28] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 29] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 30] 0x00007f6189a23cfc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044284
[ 31] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 32] 0x00007f6189a23cfc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044284
[ 33] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 34] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 35] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 36] 0x00007f6189a23cfc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044284
[ 37] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 38] 0x00007f6189a23cfc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044284
[ 39] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 40] 0x00007f6189a23cfc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044284
[ 41] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 42] 0x00007f6189a23d35 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwir_xfmr.so+00044341
[ 43] 0x00007f618d1ed30f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_parser.so+02085647 _Z19mps_xf_fold_mf_termP15M_folder_structP9term_nodePKDsPKhPj+00000127
[ 44] 0x00007f618e2447b4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03827636
[ 45] 0x00007f618e244cee /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03828974 _Z27in_parse_M_function_for_lxeP19_m_parser_interfacePFbPvPKvPKcEPFS5_mPS5_S5_bES5_RKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPKhmP9_dsbufferSK_SK_bb+00000766
[ 46] 0x00007f618b795008 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08998920
[ 47] 0x00007f618b7d4a41 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09259585
[ 48] 0x00007f618b7d4bf4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09260020
[ 49] 0x00007f618b7d5d74 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09264500
[ 50] 0x00007f618b7d6cfd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09268477
[ 51] 0x00007f618e7e3476 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00750710 _ZN8Mlm_file7load_mfEv+00000134
[ 52] 0x00007f618e794eaf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00429743 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000031
[ 53] 0x00007f618e78be95 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00392853 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 54] 0x00007f618b7c9b4e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09214798
[ 55] 0x00007f618b7c9c0d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09214989
[ 56] 0x00007f618b74c170 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08700272
[ 57] 0x00007f618b74c37e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08700798
[ 58] 0x00007f618b74c4cf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08701135
[ 59] 0x00007f618b388539 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04752697
[ 60] 0x00007f618b386ebc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746940
[ 61] 0x00007f618b3849ea /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04737514
[ 62] 0x00007f618b384db1 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04738481
[ 63] 0x00007f618b386a63 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04745827
[ 64] 0x00007f618b386be9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746217
[ 65] 0x00007f618b43716f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05468527
[ 66] 0x00007f618b43a22a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05481002
[ 67] 0x00007f618b6dc543 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08242499
[ 68] 0x00007f618b7bf1ec /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09171436
[ 69] 0x00007f618e7e2505 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00746757 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00001509
[ 70] 0x00007f618e7e29a0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00747936 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 71] 0x00007f617ea58165 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+01102181
[ 72] 0x00007f617eb5d1d3 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02171347
[ 73] 0x00007f617eae0116 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+01659158
[ 74] 0x00007f617eae11f6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+01663478
[ 75] 0x00007f617eae90a5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+01695909
[ 76] 0x00007f617eae27cb /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+01669067
[ 77] 0x00007f617eb5f376 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02179958
[ 78] 0x00007f618b855cb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09788592
[ 79] 0x00007f618b856871 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09791601
[ 80] 0x00007f618b7e5761 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09328481
[ 81] 0x00007f618b7e69dc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09333212
[ 82] 0x00007f618b85c6ec /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09815788
[ 83] 0x00007f618b7f12e8 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09376488
[ 84] 0x00007f618b84c930 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09750832
[ 85] 0x00007f618b8d8a31 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10324529
[ 86] 0x00007f618b3879b7 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04749751
[ 87] 0x00007f618b388a4c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04753996
[ 88] 0x00007f618b386ebc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746940
[ 89] 0x00007f618b3849ea /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04737514
[ 90] 0x00007f618b384db1 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04738481
[ 91] 0x00007f618b386a63 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04745827
[ 92] 0x00007f618b386be9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746217
[ 93] 0x00007f618b43716f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05468527
[ 94] 0x00007f618b43a22a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05481002
[ 95] 0x00007f618b6dc543 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08242499
[ 96] 0x00007f618b7bee5c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09170524
[ 97] 0x00007f618e7e227e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00746110 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000862
[ 98] 0x00007f618e7e29a0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00747936 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 99] 0x00007f618b7ce1c9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09232841
[100] 0x00007f618b8fadbf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10464703
[101] 0x00007f618b8f0a5a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10422874
[102] 0x00007f618b8b9911 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10197265
[103] 0x00007f618b387b2a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04750122
[104] 0x00007f618b388a4c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04753996
[105] 0x00007f618b386ebc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746940
[106] 0x00007f618b3849ea /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04737514
[107] 0x00007f618b384db1 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04738481
[108] 0x00007f618b386a63 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04745827
[109] 0x00007f618b386be9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746217
[110] 0x00007f618b43716f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05468527
[111] 0x00007f618b43a22a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05481002
[112] 0x00007f618b6dc543 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08242499
[113] 0x00007f618b6a507e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08015998
[114] 0x00007f618b6a9058 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032344
[115] 0x00007f618b6a9107 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032519
[116] 0x00007f618b71f2c5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08516293
[117] 0x00007f618b71f792 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08517522
[118] 0x00007f618eae2769   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00788329
[119] 0x00007f618eb02474   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00918644 _Z32mnRunPathDependentInitializationv+00000036
[120] 0x00007f618eae45a3   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00796067 _ZN11mcrInstance26init_on_interpreter_threadEP11MfileReaderP13MexFileReader+00000483
[121] 0x00007f6199121d6c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so+04328812 _ZNK5boost9function0IbEclEv+00000028
[122] 0x00007f618eaed8e5   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00833765
[123] 0x00007f618eaf3d09   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00859401 _ZN5boost6detail17task_shared_stateINS_3_bi6bind_tIbPFbRKNS_8functionIFbvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEbE6do_runEv+00000025
[124] 0x00007f618eaf443b   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00861243 _ZN5boost6detail22task_base_shared_stateIbE3runEv+00000059
[125] 0x00007f618eaf4497   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00861335
[126] 0x00007f618eacb75a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00694106
[127] 0x00007f618ee3ec06   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00969734


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: Did you see `If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 It's not possible to report because I don't have my licence number if I can't start the program. Maybe my university can help me get the licence numbers so I can report the error. I can try from a different account or with a different computer to see if this problem is specific for ubuntu or java-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/` there are 3 files that need to be linked to the OS libraries, which are different that those than Matlab was compiled against.

To do this you need to type the following at a terminal

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 libgfortran.so.3
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0.0.0 libquadmath.so.0
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 libstdc++.so.6
```

These changes resolved the problem for me in 14.04.4. I assume also that `libquadmath0:amd64` and `libgfortran3:amd64` are installed already. If not enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libquadmath0:amd64 libgfortran3:amd64
```

Comment: Is your system amd64? This method does not work in my system http://askubuntu.com/q/765455/25388

Comment: Yes, that's correct but I don't have an nvidia gpu. Can you try to start your Matlab with this options: `matlab -desktop -softwareopengl`