# How to Run Matlab 2016a with Nvidia Drivers of GTX-960 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, matlab

System: i7 of 2013, 32 GB, GTX-960 Nvidia, Asus Desktop PC. 
I get continuously system error

```
MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error:
- - 
Segmentation violation detected at Sat Apr 30 17:40:16 2016
```

I know the thread [Matlab problem on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763202/matlab-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04). I have `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main multiverse` in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I have also `matlab-support` in my system.

I know the thread [Matlab not work on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/matlab-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04) and the thread [matlab crash dump log file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758874/matlab-crash-dump-log-file) so I do

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 libgfortran.so.3
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0.0.0 libquadmath.so.0
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 libstdc++.so.6
```

but the problem still persists. Running also `sudo apt-get install libquadmath0:amd64 libgfortran3:amd64` does not solve the problem. 
I installed 64 bit Matlab 2016a in my Ubuntu 16.04. I sent the logs to the developers but no answer yet. 
Matlab initial technical support answer

> An initial investigation leads us to believe there may be a bug in
>   your graphics card drivers.
>
> Several users have reported this issue with a recent upgrade to the
>   Nvidia driver version 361.28 for Linux, and they were able to resolve
>   it by downgrading their driver to version 352.79 from the following
>   page: ...

Nvidia Devtalk about the situation [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/926199/linux/361-28-crashes-matlab-r2016a/) with bug ID 1744483. 
I downgraded the GPU driver to noveau driver, and no crash anymore at the login, not sure how long stability. 
This fix is only a short-term fix because these noveau drivers cause other crashes in other environments, and complications such as "itching" of the screen when moving windows, and now possibly also [crash](https://askubuntu.com/q/765775/25388) of Mouse control. 
Another temporary fix without downgrade running with `matlab -softwareopengl`.

---

How can you run Matlab 2016a with Nvidia Drivers of GTX-960 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: What error, specifically? Did you read [Matlab problem on ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/763202/matlab-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [Matlab not work on ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/matlab-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [matlab crash dump log file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/758874/matlab-crash-dump-log-file)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I know those threads. They do not work in my case. Please, see the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NVIDIA's driver issue and about its development. It was long unsolved in NVIDIA's side. The driver NVidia-367 driver should fix the issue 24.6.2016. Qi's answer is mostly a reproduction of my body, and cannot be rewarded.

Comment: you can now find the last update in my answer where a real working solution is provided to reflect the nvidia driver update! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with the matlab libraries: it contain old libraries as compare to ubuntu and they conflict with the new one...

you can check this for solution: [Doesn't Matlab work on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/doesnt-matlab-work-on-ubuntu-16-04/797747#797747)

or run

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

and during installation choose replace the libraries with .bek file name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this bug is under track by NVidia and could be fixed in the future release of NVidia drivers. I would suggest to try one of the these:

1. Uninstall the current nvidia driver, and then install driver 352.79 as suggested by Matlab.

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

   Notice that nvidia-352 driver may break your internal display screen as known for some newest machines.
2. Turn on the software-openGL option when you start up Matlab. You can either do this in a terminal with 

   `matlab -softwareopengl`

   or make a shortcut on your desktop with a file named as Matlab.desktop and filled with the following content:

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Version=9.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=true
   Exec=matlab -softwareopengl
   Name=MATLAB
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/matlab.png
   Categories=Development;Math;Science
   Comment=Scientific computing environment
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit`

   After making the shortcut, you need to make it work by typing in terminal

   `cd ~/Desktop
   sudo chmod +x Matlab.desktop`

   Now if you double click the Desktop icon, it should work.

Ref: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/926199/linux/361-28-crashes-matlab-r2016a/

Hopefully NVidia will fix this problem in their next release of driver!

**Update on Jun 23, 2016:**

Recently, I have noticed that the last update of NVidia-367 driver has fixed this problem.

To install the nvidia-367 driver in Ubuntu 16.04, you need to uninstall the previous nvidia driver first:

`sudo apt purge nvidia*`

followed by a reboot of your computer.

Then install the new driver by adding the ppa and retrieving the package from the repo.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install NVidia-367`

After a successful reboot, you should see the new driver has been added to your module list.

`lsmod | grep nvidia`

Source: http://i2000s.github.io/2016/06/23/nvidia-driver-update-for-matlab-2016a.html

Comment: This answer goes outside the question. I know these things. See for instance my other thread http://askubuntu.com/q/765820/25388 where you answer would be more appropriate. I am more interested how to fix the case WITHOUT NVidia. I cannot wait for their fix.

Comment: This option `matlab -softwareopengl` does not work anymore alone in my system. I do not understand the reason. I think downgrade is the only way to go now. Noveau drivers have also stop working.

Comment: No hurt to try if you know how to purge and reinstall as I have suggested in my answer. If worse comes worse, just try a fresh reinstallation of Ubuntu. Good luck!