# Move Mouse with Many Lines in Google Chrome?

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, 16.04, usability

In Mouse settings, I get only

[image]

where I cannot change to scroll many lines. 
So I want to move many lines only in Google Chrome. 
I cannot find the feature in Settings > Search Mouse and Select the view.

### Nvidia Noveau drivers crash with mouse [solved]

System: Nvidia GTX-960 with noveau drivers because the latest proprietary drivers crash with Matlab 2016a. 
I want to configure my mouse but I get internal error when launching mouse -application. I sent reports to Canonical.

This problem can be GPU problem because I see "itching" of the screen sometimes when moving the window.

**Solution**: use official Nvidia drivers and start Matlab by `matlab -softwareopengl`.

---

How to Scroll Many Lines with Mouse in Google Chrome of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed

If you don't want to bother with installing and configuring the imwheel package, you can just change the scrolling speed in Firefox or Chrome directly (google "firefox scroll speed" or "chrome scroll speed" for details).

Comment: I apologize -- it appears it's no longer a direct Chrome option. However, there are several different free extensions for Chrome that allow you to change the "step size" for mouse scrolling.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en

or 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?hl=en

will allow you to change the "step size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instructions on changing your scroll speed system-wide, please see the [Increase mouse wheel scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed) discussion on AskUbuntu.

If you don't want to bother with installing and configuring the imwheel package, you can just change the scrolling speed in your web browser; this will only affect your web browser and no other applications on your computer.

In Firefox you can change the scroll speed in the `about:config` options  (google "firefox scroll speed" for details).

If you use Chrome or Chromium as your browser, there is no longer a *direct* option to adjust scroll speed. However, you can adjust it by installing one of the following extensions:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?hl=en

and then adjusting the "step size" in the extension's preferences.